# Browser javascript: TLS sequence number authentication

Tags: authenticated-encryption, implementation

I am implementing TLS (or something like it perhaps) because [the browser doesn't seem to provide a direct client-script interface to TLS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/267280/can-a-client-script-provide-to-the-browser-a-certificate-to-accept-in-a-wss-c). The browser provides a `SubtleCrypto.encrypt()` function that claims to do AES-GCM. However, the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt) for this function does not mention an input for [RFC 5246/5116 AEAD Associated Data A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5116#page-5) which is authenticated but not encrypted.

Is there a way to use the existing `SubtleCrypto.encrypt()` function that includes the standard Associated Data A in a TLS-compatible way?

If not, then at minimum I would like to include the SN (TLS Sequence Number) somewhere, to prevent full-record replay attacks. Apart from TLS incompatibility, are there any potential drawbacks to simply adding the SN onto the session IV (which *is* an input to `SubtleCrypto.encrypt()`?)

TLS 1.2 definitely requires the SN in AEAD but maybe I don't care? (Does anyone still use TLS 1.2?)

The last time I implemented TLS 1.3, it had the SN in *both* the IV and AEAD Associated Data A. But AEAD may have been deprecated since then. Maybe that's why `SubtleCrypto.encrypt()` doesn't have the AEAD Associated Data A input? Surely the SN doesn't need to be included twice?

Comment: Why would SubtleCrypto support TLS at all? That's for application level encryption, for whatever that's worth. And yes, it is a crappy interface. Not sure why you would implement TLS in JavaScript either, how are you going to perform the trust verification without certificate store? That's the whole problem with SubtleCrypto. Although it is supposedly subtle, it entirely forgot about the key management it seems.

Comment: Oh, it seems to be available, try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AesGcmParams